# Two Factor Logins on Azure Portal

Tags: security, azure

What am I missing here?  I'm thinking of moving my data center to Azure.  I've created a corporate virtual network that has my ADs, my certificates, basically the family jewels of the company that I'm trying to build in the cloud.  I've plugged up every obvious security hole that I can think of except one: the login to the Azure Portal is just a simple user id/password.  If someone picked off my Microsoft Live user id, all they need is a password cracker.  And a disgruntled or dismissed employee could easily cause havoc.  Is there some way to lock down the portal?  Does anyone in the security business think these Azure web sites are secure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is polling for opinions and is not trying to solve a specific *programming*  problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure AD to properly secure the portal authentication. Azure AD is designed to securely authenticate applications in the cloud and it is supported by the majority of Microsoft solutions like Azure Portal. It will provide features like MFA, access control, self-service password reset, etc.

Although Microsoft Accounts also support some of these features, you can't force your users to specific policies, that's why Azure AD is important for enterprise level security.

Once you create a directory for your company through Azure Portal and synchronize your AD objects with Azure AD using the AAD Connect tool you will be able to login to Azure Portal using your corporate credentials and force users to use Multi-factor authentication or even apply other policies.

[Azure Active Directory features and capabilities](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/azure-active-directory-features)

[Azure Active Directory Hybrid Identity Design Considerations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-hybrid-identity-design-considerations-overview/)

[Integrating your on-premises identities with Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/)